Как указать значение "web_app" в quick_markup?
Я не могу в Quick_markup добавить веб-приложение, прошу о помощи.
Я пытался выполнить следующий код:
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Привет!', reply_markup=quick_markup({"Открыть веб приложение":{"web_app":"https://florestdev.github.com/clicker-html"}}))

Но он не заработал, ищу варианты.

Добавьте импорт:
from telebot.types import WebAppInfo

и замените свой код на такой:
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Привет!', reply_markup=quick_markup({"Открыть веб приложение": {'web_app': WebAppInfo('https://florestdev.github.com/clicker-html')}}))

